# PostgreSQL how do I COUNT with a condition?

Tags: postgresql, count, case

Can someone please assist with a query I am working on for school using a sample database from PostgreSQL tutorial? Here is my query in PostgreSQL that gets me the raw data that I can export to excel and then put in a pivot table to get the needed counts. The goal is to make a query that counts so I don't have to do the manual extraction to excel and subsequent pivot table:

```
SELECT
i.film_id, 
r.rental_id
FROM
rental as r
INNER JOIN inventory as i ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
ORDER BY film_id, rental_id
;
```

From the database this gives me a list of films (by film_id) showing each time the film was rented (by rental_id). That query works fine if just exporting to excel. Since we don't want to do that manual process what I need is to add into my query how to count how many times a given film (by film_id) was rented. The results should be something like this (just showing the first five here, the query need not do that):

```
film_id | COUNT of rental_id
1       | 23
2       | 7
3       | 12
4       | 23
5       | 12
```

Database setup instructions can be found here: [LINK](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/postgresql-sample-database/)

I have tried using COUNTIF and CASE (following other posts here) and I can't get either to work, please help.

Comment: The link leads to a tar file that literally takes 30 seconds to import and then delete when done and I included the query needed to get the relevant data. Guess you cant please everyone?

Comment: What happens to this post if the link doesn't work any further in 10 days? Future readers that get interested in this post will most likely to be hanging because you didn't add relevant data to it. This is not my standards, it's SO standards, given the link I've posted to you in my previous comment.

Comment: So your saying that to ask this question I need to include all the create statements and applicable insert values just so that some future person might be able to replicate my database (in case that link goes down)?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Your last action is instead called "[vandalizing your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372007/should-we-say-vandalizing-to-refer-to-defaced-content)", to use Stack Overflow terms, and it is not a tolerated behaviour.

Comment: No, not "your database". You do not want that, nobody else wants that. But yes, all the statements needed to create **a** database which allows to demonstrate your problem and which also allows to test proposed solutions.

Comment: Effectively attempting to remove the question which somebody spent time on to help you with  is paying them a disservice. While they are happy to help you (fair assumption on my part there...) they very likely also want the potential reward they get from other users if they deem their work to be a good answer to an interesting question. Which is unlikely if the question reads "thanks". Concepts lile that might have been clear to you already (though they seem somewhat intuitive to me...) if you had decided to take the[tour] when it was recommended to you.

Comment: You said I needed to include all the information for table creation (so people in the future would fully understand the question) and since I didn't do that (nor do I have time to go back and fix it) I thought I should withdraw my question, so I did? For what it's worth, my problem was solved by another user in a fraction of the time that we have spent going back and forth over what I should have done or what I did wrong in my initial post. There is something to be said about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?:

```
SELECT
i.film_id, 
COUNT(1)
FROM
rental as r
INNER JOIN inventory as i ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
GROUP BY i.film_id
ORDER BY film_id;
```

If there can be >1 `rental_id` in your data you may want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT r.rental_id)`

Comment: That works however what do you mean when you say "If there can be >1 rental_id in your data"? Are you asking can there be rental_id's with duplicate numbers, I don't follow?

Comment: You may have another dimension in your data where your join returns >1 rental_id record per film_id. without seeing your data my answer is based on an assumption